# What is the order of assignment in mysql?

Tags: mysql

What is the order of assignment in mysql?

```
set @rownum := 0;
explain select actor_id, first_name, @rownum as rownum
from actor
where @rownum <= 1
order by first_name, LEAST(0, @rownum:=@rownum + 1);
```

Comment: Hello! Can you give us more details about your problem? So we can help you better!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking in this query spits out 2 rows with 2 row numbers for example given

```
+----------+-------+
| sudentid | fname |
+----------+-------+
|      101 | NULL  |
|      103 | NULL  |
|      112 | NULL  |
+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the query produces

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| sudentid | fname | rownum |
+----------+-------+--------+
|      101 | NULL  |      1 |
|      103 | NULL  |      2 |
+----------+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

with an explain plan of

```
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | student | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    8 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The explain plan is in line with my expectation that order by is pretty much last (https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)

but what appears to happening is that because the order by increments a variable that is used in the select there is another where clause invoked in the ACTUAL order of events which is not reflected in the explain plan (which I think reflects the LOGICAL order of events).

I don't know what the OP is trying to do here (or if the result is incorrect) but this is NOT the way row numbers would usually be assigned prior to version 8.